# Como definir una lista de muchos elementos

Tags: c#, lista

Estoy tratando de definir una lista de un monton de elementos, tantos elementos que ni siquiera me compila.

```
        long longitud = 100000;
        List<int> lista = new List<int>(longitud);
```

El problema es que pone que no se puede convertir de long a int.
Agradeceria si alguien me indica como se pueden hacer listas con un numero elevado de elementos o si existe algun otro tipo de dato similiar a la lista que pueda utilizar,

Edit:
Pongo todo el codigo para que quien quiera pueda probar y ver si hay alguna otra estructura diferente a List que permita esto.

```
namespace Tiempos
{
class Program
{
    private const long longitud = 100000;
    private const int vueltas = 1000;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        long resA = 0;
        long resB = 0;
        for (int a = 0; a < vueltas; a++)
        {
            resA += lanzaNormal();
            resB += lanzaLista();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Media metodo normal: " + (resA / vueltas).ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Media metodo lista: " + (resB / vueltas).ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }


    private static long lanzaNormal()
    {

        int[] array = new int[longitud];
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        { array[i] = -1; }

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        int totales = 0;
        while (totales != longitud)
        {
            long a = Convert.ToInt32(r.NextDouble() * (longitud - 1));
            if (array[a] == -1)
            {
                totales++;
                array[a] = 0;
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();
        //Console.WriteLine("Total de milisegundos: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    private static long lanzaLista()
    {
        int[] array = new int[longitud];
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        { array[i] = -1; }

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        List<int> lista = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < longitud; i++)
        {
            lista.Add(i);
        }

        Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

        int totales = 0;
        while (totales != longitud)
        {
            long a = Convert.ToInt32(r.NextDouble() * (longitud - 1));
            array[a] = 0;
            lista.RemoveAt(a); // Esto no compila por ser long en vez de int                    
            totales++;
        }


        sw.Stop();
        //Console.WriteLine("Total de milisegundos: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

}
```

}

Gracias.

Comment: Un par de cosas. Ahora mismo, el código que pones no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta original, ya que esta a mutado a algo como "con que estructura de datos obtendré mayor rendimiento". Por el otro...no entiendo el código que pones. Que sentido tiene llenar de "0" el array de forma aleatoria en lugar de secuencial?

Comment: @Pikoh Buenas, la idea original de la pregunta es buscar el mejor rendimiento, por eso necesito muchos elementos para que el resultado sea el mas fidedigno. Relleno de 0 en la segunda parte para ver luego que efectivamente todas las posiciones del array han cambiado .

Comment: O sea, que no es un código "util", sino simplemente una manera de medir el rendimiento?

Comment: @pikoh, eso es, la primera vez que funcione comprobare que todos los elementos de los arrays estan bien, y luego las pruebas las hare sin ese codigo y refinando el resto. Pero sobre todo lo que intento buscar es una estructura tipo list pero que se pueda definir con un nuevo muy elevado de elementos, y la pena es que no encuentro nada :(

Comment: que es "un numero muy elevado de elementos" para ti?

Comment: @pikoh pues un Int32 o Int64

Comment: Esos números no son tan elevados aunque lo parezcan. No creo que aprecies diferencias significativas de rendimiento entre diferentes colecciones. Como digo en la edición de la respuesta, muchas veces son "microoptimizaciones" que no van a ningun lado y hacen perder el tiempo. Yo te recomiendo que uses cualquiera para el proyecto que tengas en mente, y sólo si realmente ves un rendimiento pobre ,pienses en la optimización. Es mi opinión personal simplemente :)

Answer (score 6):

`100000` no son *tantos elementos* , el problema es que el constructor de `List<T>` que espera una capacidad, espera un `int`, no un `long`. Si cambias el tipo de la variable `longitud` compilará:

```
int longitud = 100000;
List<int> lista = new List<int>(longitud);
```

De todas maneras, no se porqué restringes la capacidad en el constructor, cuando `List` es una clase que es dinámica y va creciendo automáticamente al ir añadiendo elementos.

**Editado**

Como bien dice @SJuan76, `List` usa internamente un `array`, por lo que definir una capacidad máxima a priori aumenta el rendimiento de la lista ya que no tiene que redimensionar el array interno.

Esto es correcto, pero yo siempre abogo por no preocuparse demasiado por las "microoptimizaciones". En este caso, aunque es cierto lo comentado anteriormente, esta optimización se refiere únicamente al proceso de añadir(y tal vez quitar) elementos a la lista. La diferencia de rendimiento en este proceso, en un numero de elementos no demasiado grandes como pueden ser 100000 en el caso que nos ocupa, es prácticamente imperceptible.

Comment: El caso es que estoy probando a ver que seria mas rapido a la hora de rellenar un array con posiciones random, si como toda la vida, generando la posicion random y ver si ya estaba rellena o no o creando una lista con tantos elementos como posiciones del array, que rellene el array de la posicion random que se genera y luego elimina ese elemento del array, asi solo hay que generar tantos elementos random como elementos tiene el array y te aseguras que siempre rellena una posicion nueva del array. Por eso busco algo como la lista per con mas capacidad

Comment: `no se porqué restringes la capacidad en el constructor` [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dw8e0z9z(v=vs.110).aspx) trabaja internamente con arrays; si se incrementa la capacidad elemento a elemento hace necesarios redimensionamientos (crear nuevo array y copiar elemento) que pueden afectar al rendimiento. Si sabes la capacidad estimada te puedes ahorrar eso. Y por supuesto, no "limitas" la capacidad; se pueden seguir añadiendo elementos por encima de la capacidad preestablecida.

Comment: @SJuan76 tienes razón, aunque la verdad yo nunca he usado ese constructor. Pero si, obviamente añadiendo una capacidad por defecto aumentas el rendimiento sin duda.No lo había pensado, gracias por comentarlo.

Comment: @Veelicus si expones exactamente que necesitas es posible que haya una estructura mas adecuada. De todas maneras, como bien dice SJuan76, la implementación `List` internamente utiliza un array

Comment: @Pikoh He añadido el codigo que he hecho para que se vea mas claro lo que intento conseguir, indico que linea es la que no me compila por ser long en vez de int. Busco alguna otra estructura similar a List para hacer esto con un numero de elementos muy grande.